# CSS combination of relative+fixed without jump effect

Tags: html, css, scroll, web

I want to give to the header-body the effect like in this site [preview.oklerthemes.com/?theme=Porto](http://preview.oklerthemes.com/?theme=Porto)

Use a relative position (to show the scroll)...and the use the fixed.. but when I put the fixed position I see that this come to the original position AND THEN come up. --> https://jsfiddle.net/uxhgpz6e/2/

`enter`

So, i'd like to avoid this "jump effect", but still use the relative+fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop content jumping up behind fixed nav using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953618/how-to-stop-content-jumping-up-behind-fixed-nav-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Change your scroll value and it should get the behaviour you want : [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxhgpz6e/10/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

        if($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
              $('.header-body').css('position','fixed').css('top','-100px');
        } else {
            $('.header-body').css('position','relative').css('top','0');

        }    
});
```

Comment: I want to still use relative+fixed after a determinate margin so i can riproduce the effect in the www.preview.oklerthemes.com/?theme=Porto site for the header-body

Comment: May I suggest you add `position: sticky` and then use the script as fallback

Comment: Yes, you can edit my answer and add `position: sticky` code part also, and you can also add a link to http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky since it's not yet a complete supported browser feature :)